# Can I use Microsoft windows phone tutorial code in my published app?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I was wondering if I can use Microsoft MSDN tutorial code and build my apps around that? Or is it illegal? Do I need cite my sources?

Comment: If you want legal advice you should always ask a lawyer. Not just random people on the internet

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft usually, if not always, have a legal document as part of their samples download, that tells you precisely what you can do with it.

But as a general rule, you can use everything they provided you with, fully legit. Don't expect problems from Microsoft, when you're developing for their own platform :-)

Also, most of their code samples is licensed as MS-PL, which is a open source license.